# объясните,как работает n-=1

Tags: python

У меня есть такой код,объясните как работает в нем `n-=1`

Код:

```
fib1 = 0
fib2 = 1 

n = int(input("Номер элемента ряда Фибоначчи: ")) -2 #вычитаем первые два значения которые уже учли

while  n > 0:
    fib_sum = fib1 + fib2 # по формуле находим искомое число 
    fib1 = fib2 #приравниваем fib1 и fib2 чтобы в следующий расчетах был известен fib1
    fib2 = fib_sum # задаём в fib2 искомое число чтобы в следующий расчетах был известен fib2
    n -= 1 

print(fib2)
```

Comment: `n = n - 1` *(4 символа нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor лайфхак: нужную длину комментария с кодом легко получить, просто дублируя символы «`». :)

Comment: Не будем забывать и про: n+=1 и n*=1 и т.д

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем примере декремент n-= - это просто укороченная запись выражения n=n-1. Pyhton позволяет некоторые вольности с подобными операторами. Например, можно использовать даже такое выражение:

```
n = 1
n-=-1 # У этого оператора есть даже название invader, по мотивам старой компьютерной игры
print(n)

#2
```

Однако, например `n+=a` далеко не всегда равно `n=n+a`:

```
a = [1]
b = a
a+=[2]
print(a)
print(b)
print(a is b)

#[1, 2]
#[1, 2]
#True
```

Но:

```
a = [1]
b = a
a = a+[2]
print(a)
print(b)
print(a is b)

#[1, 2]
#[1]
#False
```

Answer (score 3):

```
n -= 1
```

это скрашенное:

```
n = n - 1
```

в данном случае, вы вводите число и цикл **while** будет работать пока **n** станет равно 0